# Android:typeface Error: types not allowed. 

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, textview, typeface

I am creating a style xml document, and I've ran into a problem. I want to use the droid serif  font, but I can't use it in an emulator, only in the preview screen in Eclipse. Sometimes I can write `<Item name="android:typeface">2</item>` without getting an error, but when I try to run the program in the Android Emulator, I get an error: `error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'android:typeface' with value '2').` When i press `ctrl+space` to see what I can write it shows (among others) `serif`, however when i write `<Item name="android:typeface">serif</item>` it says `The word 'serif' is not correctly spelled.`.

Here's the part from the .xml file:

```
<style name="Header">
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#444444</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">15dp</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
  <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a spell checker for string values in XML...usually you get the "not correctly spelled" thing if it is a word that the spell checker does not recognize. It should still compile and work though, if this is actually the case. Maybe that's what's going on here?

Comment: If this is the case: you can select the word, right click, and select "Quick Fix" to disable the spell checker, add the word to the dictionary, ignore, etc.

Comment: Wow.. I really thought it would be something a little less basic than this. Thanks.